# Rare crash as a result of thread cleanup (NSFinalizeThreadData)

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

The QA engineers at my office have come across a crash for which the stack appears to be quite unusual.  Having looked up `NSFinalizeThreadData` on Google and found only 5 results, I thought I would throw this experience out into the world and see if anyone else has seen something similar.

```
Thread 118 Crashed:: com.mycompany.mycontroller
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x92eec4a7 objc_msgSend + 23
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x9a5d102f -[NSView removeFromSuperview] + 546
2   com.mycompany.myapplication 0x004d6536 -[MyController dealloc] + 105
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x92f025ef -[NSObject release] + 47
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x902975e2 __NSFinalizeThreadData + 1468
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x97dd0be2 __CFTSDFinalize + 82
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b23a87d _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 190
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b23727e _pthread_exit + 108
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b2371e8 pthread_exit + 33
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x90297026 +[NSThread exit] + 18
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x90270e7e __NSThread__main__ + 1450
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b2365fb _pthread_body + 144
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b236485 _pthread_start + 130
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b23bcf2 thread_start + 34
```

It seems that the thread being closed here somehow has acquired ownership of the MyController object.  Perhaps this is because of the following:

```
-(void) startMyControllerThread
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(runLoop) withObject:nil];
}
```

I'm thinking that performing a selector in this way may give the new thread ownership of self, which is then cleaned up when `runLoop` falls out of scope?  If this is the case, I will need to determine why the view being removed from superview is no longer actually an `NSView`.

Is anyone able to shed some light on `NSFinalizeThreadData` and confirm or deny that `performSelector*` methods result in the receiver being owned by the new thread?

Comment: You can not make UI calls from non-main thread.

Comment: Show the code for `runLoop`. There is no ownership unless you create it. The last reference to the controller is destroyed with the thread is all.

Comment: No ownership is created in `runLoop`, which is why I'm confused about the release occurring here.  Thanks hamster and sorry I doubted you, it seems the background thread performing the selector may in fact be to blame for this issue.  This dealloc typically occurs on the main thread anyways, so the thread performing the selector has been an oversight.

Comment: it looks an awful lot like the view isn't valid by the time you get to [MyController dealloc]...

Comment: and thread 118 isn't where you should see [NSView removeFromSuperview]

Comment: It appears that calling `removeFromSuperview` on a background thread will indeed cause a crash :S.  I am still perplexed about this stack though, and very curious about the reason that `NSFinalizeThreadData` is responsible for releasing this controller.